# Laravel migration to add index in Postgresql and verify result

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm trying to add an index to postgresql using a Laravel migration. I've shown below what I have so far, which doesn't seem to work, because after I run the migration successfully, if I re-run the migration (for example, by creating a 2nd migration file with similar code), the $indexesFound array is empty.

Here is just the "up" section of the migration. Please note that I have to pass in the connection string because I am working with multiple database connections in my project, and the postgresconnection is not the default connection.

```
  public function up()
   {
       Schema::connection('postgresconnection')->table('sometable', static function (Blueprint $table) {
           $schemaManager = Schema::getConnection('postgresconnection')->getDoctrineSchemaManager();

           $indexesFound  = $schemaManager->listTableIndexes('sometable');

           // always shows empty array, even if I re-run the migration
           print_r($indexesFound)
       
           if (!array_key_exists('idx_myindex', $indexesFound)) {
                $table->index('myfield', 'idx_myindex');
           }
       });
   }
```

My questions are:

- is this the correct way to add an index to postgresql using a Laravel migration?
- why is $indexesFound always showing an empty array in the above code? (is there some way that I can show the indexes on my table to ensure that I don't re-add an index?)